# How to set Associated View as default view in crm 2013.?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

How to set Associated View as default view in crm 2013. ?

I am in Account Entity.

1. In Notes& Activity Section
2. Activity shows Open Activity as a default view.
3. It's not allow me to set Open Activity Associated View to default view .

Is there any way to do this customization in crm 2013

Answer (score 2):

In your solution under Entities -> Activity-> Views you will see a list of all the views associated with activities.  You will see that "Open Activities" has a type of "Default Public View" and that a number of other views including all those that you create will have a type of "Public View."  Select the public view that you would like to be default and under the "More Actions" drop-down select "Set Default."

Edit:
On second read of your question I notice that you may have already tried this and the issue is that you can only set a public view to be the default view.  You should create a public view that is identical to your Associated View and set that to be the default public view.

Comment: Thanks for reply...Your second solution seems to be helpful for me

Comment: The problem with the Activity associated views is that you can't reproduce the behaviour that makes them include "roll up" of activities from child and grandchild (etc) records.